# PHP Browser Detection and Redirection

Tags: php, browser

All,

My application supports IE7+, MOZILLA and other modern browsers. Anybody know of a very good browser detection and redirection PHP class? I came across this, but I am not sure if anybody used this:

http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/#typicalusage

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817155/php-mobile-browser-detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All you need is get_browser() and a recent browscap.ini that maps the user-agent string to a browser/version and its capabilities.
>   You can get a usually very up-to-date browscap.ini version from http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp

Source:@VolkerK

> [WURLF](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) is the ultimate way for mobile browser detection and a PHP API is available

Source:kgiannakakis

Comment: According to a link on the redirected page mentioned above:  "This site and related update URLs will be disabled on 30th March 2014.
Visit Browscap.org for all new updates. You will need to update any scripts to use the new URLs."

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP [get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

> get_browser — Tells what the user's
>   browser is capable of