# How do i detect any cell phone navigator with php?

Tags: php, mobile

I only need to detect if is mobile device or not...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mobile browser detection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817155/php-mobile-browser-detection)

Comment: hi... when i inserted the answer the stackoverflow ajax autosuggest didnt show me that question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good class to try:

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Comment: hi thanks a lot im getting this error when in invoke the function

Comment: hi thanks a lot im getting this error: 
Notice: Undefined variable: accept in C:\Servidor_Apache\htdocs\INTERSOLUCIONESCR\Descuenticos\ver3\mobile\Mobile_Detect.php on line 40

Notice: Undefined property: Mobile_Detect::$isIphone in C:\Servidor_Apache\htdocs\INTERSOLUCIONESCR\Descuenticos\ver3\mobile\Mobile_Detect.php on line 80                                     when in invoke the function isMobile() What that means????

Comment: It's a known bug: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/issues/detail?id=7  In the ticket it shows how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this if you want to know which device it is:
http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-php.htm

Or if you don't care:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php

Answer (score 0):

This is updated version of the PHP Mobile Detect:

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect2/