# How to determine if mobile or tab is used using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] for getting the width of the page

Tags: php, mobile, tablet

How do i determine whether the page is opened using a tablet or a mobile phone, i get that you can check for iPhone, iPad, etc. but is there a more distinct identifier in determining whether the page was opened using mobile, or tablet?

I'm using this so i can get the width of the page, but if there is a more efficient way of getting the current width of the page, do let me know

thank you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636306/mobile-browser-detection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817155/php-mobile-browser-detection

Comment: and if they're coming in using a google Nexus 10, which has a resolution of 2560x1600? That's far higher than my desktop monitors, yet one's mobile and one's not...

Comment: @MarcB true, how will you go around it then?

Comment: "mobile" is getting to be a pointless definition, since your average "about a year old" smartphone has screens with higher resolution than your average cheapie "good enough for grandma" desktop machine. mobile v.s. "full" made sense when mobile meant a dinky 150x300 screen viewing via WAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php  You may need some JavaScript to get the dimensions of the viewport.

Comment: what kind of javascript function would i need to know for this?

Comment: See http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1015 And there may be something good in jQuery.