# Show Google Adsense code depending on the result of PHP or Javascript IF and ELSE Test

Tags: php, if-statement, media-queries, adsense

Do you know how to code a PHP script or Javascript that detects the screen size of the user then perform a IF and else test then the result will return a specific display?

What I'm trying to accomplish here:

1. Javascript will detect the resolution of the user/ visitor of my website. *(I got this 
   using media queries, i have no problem on this part)*
2. then A Script  will perform a IF and ELSE Function. If the user's resolution is = <320x480 (resolution for mobilephone), the PHP script will call the codes for Google Adsense - Mobile Phones. If not, then it will display the code for Google Adsense Websites.

The 2 google adsense codes are saved in two different files, let's just call them adsense-Mobile.php and adsense-Website.php

here's a simple flowchart.

[image: Flow chart]

Here lies the problem i encountered. ***Many experts says that a simple SHOW-HIDE element in Jquery will do the job.* Unfortunately, in my case, it didn't.**

I already did that and it doesn't meet my requirements. The problem is the two Ads from google is loaded in the website all at once and only 1 is diplayed. Google Adsense only allow 3 advertisements to be display. If i do the show-hide jquery, i will be loosing the  opportunity to generate income since one of the ads is hidden. I need something that will not load the two codes BUT only **calls** the right one (correct size, either for mobile or websites).

I know PHP can do this, but I don't know where to start or what function should i start to read or research. Need your help badly. Any ideas? Any PHP or javascript that can **call** only one google adsense codes depending on the resolution.

here's the code for google adsense Mobile and Website.

**Code for Google Adsense - WEBSITES**

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-6099979626157131";
/* Ben Daggers Leader Board */
google_ad_slot = "8829449662";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

**Code for Google Adsense - MOBILE**

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['google']['client']='ca-mb-pub-6099979626157131';
$GLOBALS['google']['https']=read_global('HTTPS');
$GLOBALS['google']['ip']=read_global('REMOTE_ADDR');
$GLOBALS['google']['markup']='xhtml';
$GLOBALS['google']['output']='xhtml';
$GLOBALS['google']['ref']=read_global('HTTP_REFERER');
$GLOBALS['google']['slotname']='8668582435';
$GLOBALS['google']['url']=read_global('HTTP_HOST') . read_global('REQUEST_URI');
$GLOBALS['google']['useragent']=read_global('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
$google_dt = time();
google_set_screen_res();
google_set_muid();
google_set_via_and_accept();
function read_global($var) {
  return isset($_SERVER[$var]) ? $_SERVER[$var]: '';
}

function google_append_url(&$url, $param, $value) {
  $url .= '&' . $param . '=' . urlencode($value);
}

function google_append_globals(&$url, $param) {
  google_append_url($url, $param, $GLOBALS['google'][$param]);
}

function google_append_color(&$url, $param) {
  global $google_dt;
  $color_array = explode(',', $GLOBALS['google'][$param]);
  google_append_url($url, $param,
                    $color_array[$google_dt % count($color_array)]);
}

function google_set_screen_res() {
  $screen_res = read_global('HTTP_UA_PIXELS');
  if ($screen_res == '') {
    $screen_res = read_global('HTTP_X_UP_DEVCAP_SCREENPIXELS');
  }
  if ($screen_res == '') {
    $screen_res = read_global('HTTP_X_JPHONE_DISPLAY');
  }
  $res_array = preg_split('/[x,*]/', $screen_res);
  if (count($res_array) == 2) {
    $GLOBALS['google']['u_w']=$res_array[0];
    $GLOBALS['google']['u_h']=$res_array[1];
  }
}

function google_set_muid() {
  $muid = read_global('HTTP_X_DCMGUID');
  if ($muid != '') {
    $GLOBALS['google']['muid']=$muid;
     return;
  }
  $muid = read_global('HTTP_X_UP_SUBNO');
  if ($muid != '') {
    $GLOBALS['google']['muid']=$muid;
     return;
  }
  $muid = read_global('HTTP_X_JPHONE_UID');
  if ($muid != '') {
    $GLOBALS['google']['muid']=$muid;
     return;
  }
  $muid = read_global('HTTP_X_EM_UID');
  if ($muid != '') {
    $GLOBALS['google']['muid']=$muid;
     return;
  }
}

function google_set_via_and_accept() {
  $ua = read_global('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
  if ($ua == '') {
    $GLOBALS['google']['via']=read_global('HTTP_VIA');
    $GLOBALS['google']['accept']=read_global('HTTP_ACCEPT');
  }
}

function google_get_ad_url() {
  $google_ad_url = 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/ads?';
  google_append_url($google_ad_url, 'dt',
                    round(1000 * array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()))));
  foreach ($GLOBALS['google'] as $param => $value) {
    if (strpos($param, 'color_') === 0) {
      google_append_color($google_ad_url, $param);
    } else if (strpos($param, 'url') === 0) {
      $google_scheme = ($GLOBALS['google']['https'] == 'on')
          ? 'https://' : 'http://';
      google_append_url($google_ad_url, $param,
                        $google_scheme . $GLOBALS['google'][$param]);
    } else {
      google_append_globals($google_ad_url, $param);
    }
  }
  return $google_ad_url;
}

$google_ad_handle = @fopen(google_get_ad_url(), 'r');
if ($google_ad_handle) {
  while (!feof($google_ad_handle)) {
    echo fread($google_ad_handle, 8192);
  }
  fclose($google_ad_handle);
}

?>
```

many Thanks! I hope i explained my question well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in php if browser [is mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636306/mobile-browser-detection) or not and make:

```
<?php
  if($isMobile){
    include('mobile_file.php');
  }
  else{
    include('website_file.php');
  }
?>
```

Comment: Good point @Narek, I will try this! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Let's remember that problem given in question is RESOLUTION depending php include, not mobile-or-not detection. If this response will solve your problem, please update your question to mobile detection, not resolution

Comment: @killer_PL problem is mobile-or-not detection which now solved by resolution check.

Answer (score 0):

I would use media queries in Javascript:

```
<head>
<script>
var mediaQuery = "(max-width:480px)", mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery), isMobile = mediaQueryList.matches;
</script>
<body>
<!-- Your HTML content, build your page, etc. -->

<script>
if (isMobile) {
    // Mobile adsense code
} else {
    //Desktop adsense code
}
</script>
</body>
```

Javascript is executed in order, so by the time the body tag closes, `isMobile` will already be set based on the media query of the page.

Answer (score -1):

Just load your adsense code by AJAX. First prepare on your page box for ads placement:

```
<div id="adsense-box"></div>
```

Now, check user browser resolution and depending on result, do proper AJAX request for Ads HTML. This example show how you can achieve it with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) ([.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function):

JavaScript:

```
if ( isMobileResolution ) {
 url = "/mobile_adsense.php";
} else {
 url = "/website_adsesne.php";
}

$.ajax({
 url: url 
}).done(function(content) {
  $("#adsense-box").html(content);
});
```

**Other solution,** without PHP:

Just send your Adsense codes not to HTML elements, but to Javascript variable, like this:

var codemobile = "";
var codewebsite = "";

than, you can append to any HTML element one of those codes, after resolution detection. Because AdSense code will not be in document DOM HTML, it will not be loaded by google and treated as "executed" - those codes will be just waiting in varaibles. Remember to escale `"` signs etc.

To catch those codes to a variable, you can swich echo with $var .= or user PHP buffering (ob_start() etc). This solutions saves you request and latency with AJAX.

**Third solution - document.write safe**

Salman A. pointed that AdSense uses document.write, so maybe prepare iframes on site, resize those iframes after resolution detections, and set src to proper .php file.

I don't know how adsense will work in iframe - be aware that contextual ad placement can be broken because of lack of content on page (iframe).

**Another soluction - totally safe, but with additional refresh/empty landing page**

You can check in JavaScript if resolution is small, and set a cookie for ad selection, and refresh a page if cookie was not previously set. Let's PHP generate proper ads code dependly on cookie value.

This solution must work but you will have single additional refresh when user is on mobile device & entering page for the first time. If you already have some landing or redirection page, maybe try to set cookies there.

You can also switch to mobile-ads-default and trait unusual with refresh only standard users, if this page is view more frequently from mobile devices

Comment: (i) AdSense code uses document.write (ii) iframes are no good either; AdSense reads the page that contains ads in order to determine relevant ads.