# How do you detect a mobile device with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, mobile

I'm looking for the best method/practice to use for detecting if a person is using a mobile device to view a website. I'd like to be able to adjust the templates of the website if a mobile device is detected so it's easier to view.

What is the most reliable and effective method for detecting mobile devices?

Comment: Please be polite. His edit was perfectly fine; see [the relevant FAQ section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [this](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect#usage) project to do that:

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    // Any mobile device.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can get the server agent and use a preg_match to check it.
for example:

```
$isMobile=(bool)preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
```

i got a better version of the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636306/mobile-browser-detection):

```
$isMobile = (bool)preg_match('#\b(ip(hone|od|ad)|android|opera m(ob|in)i|windows (phone|ce)|blackberry|tablet'.
                    '|s(ymbian|eries60|amsung)|p(laybook|alm|rofile/midp|laystation portable)|nokia|fennec|htc[\-_]'.
                    '|mobile|up\.browser|[1-4][0-9]{2}x[1-4][0-9]{2})\b#i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
```

and then you can :

```
if(isMobile())
    header("Location: http://m.site.com/");
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try the http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ libraries. has a piece of code to detect mobile browsers for almost everything you would need to be able to detect mobile browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest of use this class for a good and complete mobile detection [php-mobile-detect](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)

or you must filter the user agent

Comment: Is such a large script necessary to detect a mobile device? Seems like their methods depend on individual models of phones and their operating systems which are always changing. I wont want to have to update my software like every 3 days with the rate new phones come out.

Comment: @CoryNickerson if you want a good script, that is the best actually, otherwise you must do all manually filtering the user agent from php