# block mobile (iOS / Android) access to a single CMS page in magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento

in apache I guess i could do something like .htaccess Access Control option.

For eg:
SetEnvIf User-Agent BadBot GoAway=1
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=GoAway

but how to block mobile (iOS / Android) access to a single CMS page in magento????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the `cms_controller_router_match_before` event from the [CMS router's](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Controller/Router.php) match method and check the user agent header in the observer method. Possibly, refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3817155/833795).

```
public function checkRestrictAccess(Varien_Event_Observer $o)
{
    /**
     * Browser detection logic will go here.
     */

    if (mobile browser == true && $o->getCondition()->getIdentifier() == 'page-id') {
        $o->getRequest()->setRedirectUrl(Redirect Url);
    }
}
```