# Is there a way to load an alternate stylesheet using PHP?

Tags: php, css, mobile, stylesheet, alternate

I'm building a mobile version of my site, and at this point, creating an alternate stylesheet would suffice to make the site adept for mobile devices. I want to use a user agent detection PHP script to detect the platform, and switch stylesheets accordingly. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817155/php-mobile-browser-detection

Then just have an if/else statement echoing the HTML code used to call the stylesheet.

Comment: That's good, but the part I'm having trouble with is swapping stylesheets.

Comment: Why not use [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and style to the screen size, not the user agent

Comment: Media queries are the way to go.

Comment: That's actually brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try out a librabry to check if its a mobile device then you can try out this library: http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/ (this also supports detecting specific OSes)

and then have code like

```
if($detect->isiOS()){
    echo <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iOSstyle.css" />;
}
else if ($detect->isMobile()) {
   echo <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" />;
}
else{
  echo <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normal.css" />;
}
```

FYI, these libraries are dependent on the User-Agent value in the header and other headers too.

Comment: I tried using it to replace my current stylesheet link (before moving on to developing the mobile site, just to be safe); I get a PHP syntax error at `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css />;` (I added the semicolon)

Comment: sorry my daily dealing with asp.net just overpowers other language syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if-condition written in pseudocode because I haven't used WURLF):

```
<?php
if (device is mobile) {
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='mobile.css' />";
}else{
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='monitor.css' />";
?>
```

Put this code where you'd normally have the CSS link.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before is store the current state (mobile/desktop) in a session variable.  Then you can have a "View Desktop/Mobile Version" link which would toggle the session variable.  When you render each page, use an if statement on the session variable to determine which stylesheet to display.  I recommend you separate this logic into a function for re-use so you don't have to edit 20 different pages when refactoring.

If you want to auto-detect mobile browsers, you can use [WURLF](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/php_index.php) or [php-mobile-detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/).