# How do I get the browser in PhP?

Tags: php, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Browser Detection and Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470965/php-browser-detection-and-redirection)

I just need the browser NAME (IE, Chrome, firefox, etc), nothing else (so user agent doesn't work). What's the PhP code to do this?

Comment: Some more dupes: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967008/determine-browsers-version), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895727/how-can-i-detect-the-browser-with-php-or-javascript), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142030/any-php-code-to-detect-the-browser-with-version-and-operating-system), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209649/how-to-detect-if-browser-is-firefox-with-php?lq=1), to name a few possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Use get_browser.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: It only works if you have `browscap.ini` set up. You can't do that on a shared host.